# How can I simplify this IF(SUM() formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I wanted to stop this formula from returning 0 if the sum equalled 0.

```
SUM(INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!C5:C"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!G5:G"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!K5:K"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!O5:O"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!S5:S"))
```

But the only way I knew of doing that was to use IF(SUM(), but that causes a lot of repetition and makes the formula significantly longer than needed.

```
=IF(SUM(INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!C5:C"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!G5:G"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!K5:K"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!O5:O"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!S5:S")) = 0 , "" , 
SUM(INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!C5:C"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!G5:G"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!K5:K"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!O5:O"),INDIRECT("'"&C6&"'!S5:S")))
```

How can I simplify this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark the area you want to remove zeros from:

[image]

Choose Format --> Number --> More formats ---> Custom number format

[image]

Type: 0;-0;; as custom format

[image]

[image]

Now you have blanks instead of zeros

This works the same way as in Excel - you can find more about custom formats here:
https://exceljet.net/custom-number-formats

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how you figured out something like this, but I am extremely grateful. Thanks!